# How to disable a button till the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7jzL8gL/) and code:

```js
$(".addtowatchlistform").submit(function(e) {
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  var url = $(this).attr("action");
  var form = $(this); // Add this line
  $.post(url, data, function(data) { 
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $(form).children("button").css('color',data.watchlisticoncolor); 
  $(form).children("button").attr('data-tooltip',data.addremove + " YOUR WATCHLIST");
        $(form).children("input#addedornotsend").attr('value',data.addedornotsend); 

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("json encoding failed");
        return false;
    }
});
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form class="addtowatchlistform" action="insert.php" method="POST" >

  <input id="addedornotsend" type="hidden" name="addedornot" value="'.$addedornot.'"/>
  <button id="addtowatchlistbutton" type="submit" name="tmdb_id"  data-tooltip="'.$addremove.' YOUR WATCHLIST" class="material-icons">Submit please</button>
  <span class="result"></span> 
  </form>
```

This code submits the form without reloading the page (ajax). But the problem is, user can submit the form multiple times while the form is being submitted.

I want to disable the button while the form is being submitted. How can I do that?

Comment: set a flag that return from server, based on the flag, you can disable using javascript

Comment: `$('#addtowatchlistbutton').attr('disabled', true);`  just use it where you want make it disable .

Answer (score 4):

On form post set button disabled

```js
$(".addtowatchlistform").submit(function(e) {
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  var url = $(this).attr("action");
  var form = $(this); // Add this line
$("#addtowatchlistbutton").attr('disabled','disabled');
  $.post(url, data, function(data) { 
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $(form).children("button").css('color',data.watchlisticoncolor); 
  $(form).children("button").attr('data-tooltip',data.addremove + " YOUR WATCHLIST");
        $(form).children("input#addedornotsend").attr('value',data.addedornotsend); 
 $("#addtowatchlistbutton").removeAttr('disabled');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("json encoding failed");
$("#addtowatchlistbutton").removeAttr('disabled');
        return false;
    }
});
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form class="addtowatchlistform" action="insert.php" method="POST" >

  <input id="addedornotsend" type="hidden" name="addedornot" value="'.$addedornot.'"/>
  <button id="addtowatchlistbutton" type="submit" name="tmdb_id"  data-tooltip="'.$addremove.' YOUR WATCHLIST" class="material-icons">Submit please</button>
  <span class="result"></span> 
  </form>
```

Comment: @JoshPoor you have to remove disable on your form post success method. This is just sampling how to disable form post multiple time once the form is already posted.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. You can simply disable/hide the submit button or add an variable to track if the form is submited like the below code:

```
var isSubmited = false;
$(".addtowatchlistform").submit(function(e) {
  if (isSubmited) return false;
  isSubmited = true;
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  var url = $(this).attr("action");
  var form = $(this); // Add this line
  $.post(url, data, function(data) { 
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $(form).children("button").css('color',data.watchlisticoncolor); 
        $(form).children("button").attr('data-tooltip',data.addremove + " YOUR WATCHLIST");
        $(form).children("input#addedornotsend").attr('value',data.addedornotsend); 

    } catch (e) {
        console.log("json encoding failed");
        return false;
    }
});
  return false;
});
```

Comment: @JoshPoor: It's just a sample code to show how to use a flag ;)

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

```js
$(".addtowatchlistform").submit(function(e) {
  $("#addtowatchlistbutton").attr("disabled", true); //disable it
  
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  var url = $(this).attr("action");
  var form = $(this); // Add this line
  /*$.post(url, data, function(data) { 
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $(form).children("button").css('color',data.watchlisticoncolor); 
  $(form).children("button").attr('data-tooltip',data.addremove + " YOUR WATCHLIST");
        $(form).children("input#addedornotsend").attr('value',data.addedornotsend); 
        
    $("#addtowatchlistbutton").attr("disabled", false); //enable it
    
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("json encoding failed");
        return false;
    }
});*/
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function() {
        // callback code here
        $("#addtowatchlistbutton").attr("disabled", false); //enable it
       }
    })
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form class="addtowatchlistform" action="insert.php" method="POST" >
  <input id="addedornotsend" type="hidden" name="addedornot" value="'.$addedornot.'"/>
  <button id="addtowatchlistbutton" type="submit" name="tmdb_id"  data-tooltip="'.$addremove.' YOUR WATCHLIST" class="material-icons">Submit please</button>
  <span class="result"></span> 
</form>
```

`$("#addtowatchlistbutton").attr("disabled", true);` use this to enable/disable the element. on click disable it and on success enable it again.